# Mutilple inheritance strange behavior - Java 8

Tags: java, inheritance, java-8, default-method

In the following code if I uncomment `I3`  and implements `I2` and `I3` then there is a `compilation` failure with the following error:

> unrelated defaults for m2() from I3 and I2

Which is as fine and expected behavior.

However, when I replace `I3` with `I`, it compiles successfully and I am getting `I2` as output.

```
public class DefaultMethodTest implements I, I2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultMethodTest obj = new DefaultMethodTest();
        obj.m2();
     }
}
    
interface I {
        default void m2() {
        System.out.println("I1");
    }
}

interface I2 extends I {
        default void m2() {
        System.out.println("I2");
    }
}

//interface I3 extends I {
//
//    default void m2() {
//        System.out.println("I3");
//    }
//}
```

Now I have couple of questions here :

- Why there is no `compilation` failure in second case although both
  interface have same default method `m2`?
- Why `I2` got precedence over `I` ?.

Note: This question is not related to [java-8-default-method-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197301/java-8-default-method-inheritance)

Comment: "*In the following code if I uncomment `I3` then there is a compilation failure..*" I can't reproduce this problem. If I *only* uncomment `I3` then compilation error shouldn't appear since `I3` is not used in `public class DefaultMethodTest implements I, I2 {..}`. Your code example should probably include `I3` in `DefaultMethodTest` like `public class DefaultMethodTest implements I, I2, I3 {..}` or `public class DefaultMethodTest implements I2, I3{..}`.

Comment: BTW `System.out.println("I2");` inside `I3` should probably be `System.out.println("I3");` for clarity.

Comment: @Pshemo Done. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the default method resolution rules, the default method in the *most specific default providing interface* will be chosen. In your case, both I and I2 has a default method (each) with the same signature. Hence, it will choose I2 which is your *most specific default providing interface*.

On the other hand, if you `implement I2, I3`, there will be conflict that you need to resolve (by implementing `m2` in your class).

References:

http://www.lambdafaq.org/how-are-conflicting-method-declarations-resolved/
https://javadevcentral.com/default-method-resolution-rules

Comment: why there is no compilation failure ??

Comment: Why would it fail compilation when I2 wins over I?

Comment: I don't have a JLS link handy, but it has to do with the Inheritance between `I` and the child classes, which is lost when you inherit two hierarchically-equivalent class (`I2` and `I3`). One has a more specific method (it's a child implementation) vs the other has two equally ambiguous ones. This is also a good reason to override explicitly when you have two inherited methods with matching signatures, even if just to call one of them via `IParent.super.myMethod()`

Comment: @Rogue It doesn't have anything to do with `I`. Even if `I` weren't there, there would be a conflict when you implement `I2` and `I3`.

Comment: I'm speaking as to why `I` with a child class was being allowed, not why the other errored. We're arguing the same thing I think (method/member resolution)

Comment: @Rogue When we have `I -> I2` I2 is more specific whereas when we have `I -> I2` and `I -> I3` and we implement I2 and I3, there arises a conflict. I think we are talking about the same thing :)

Comment: I am not sure if "*most specific* default providing interface" is right term here. I thought that it meant something more along `foo(Object o){...}` `foo(Number n){...}` and if I use `foo(1)` then `foo(Number)` will be executed because `Number` is *more specific* description for `Integer` than `Object`. But in case of `class Parent{void foo(){..}}` `class Child extends Parent {@override void foo(){..} }` `class GrandChild extends Child{}` `GrandChild gc = new GrandChild(); gc.foo();` then `foo` from `Child` will be invoked because it is closest in *inheritance tree*.

Comment: Also in case where `interface I2 extends I` declaring `I` in `... implements I, I2` is redundant. It is effectively `implements I2`.

Comment: @Pshemo Method overrides are resolved at *compile* time. That is not the issue here. It is when a class inherits more than one method with the *same signature*.